# javascript animation of a water tank

Tags: javascript, rgraph

I am trying to use RGraph library to manipulate a vertical progress bar, but I'm stuck because after creating the progress bar I can't manipulate its properties, here's the code I have been using:

```
 window.onload = function ()
{
    // Create the object. The arguments are: The canvas ID, the indicated value and the maximum value.
    var myProgress = new RGraph.VProgress('myProgress', 60, 100)

        // Configure the chart to look as you want.
        .Set('chart.colors', ['blue'])

        .Set('chart.tickmarks',['true'])

        .Set('chart.tickmarks.color',['white'])

        .Set('chart.title',"Nivel")

        // Now call the .Draw() method to draw the chart.
        .Draw();




}
```

and after that I try to read the value property using a click on a button,but it says undefined:

```
function myFunction()
{
   var valor= myProgress.value;
   alert(valor);


}
```

How can I access the properties of an object created in another function? My idea is to change the level of the progress bar according to a control put in the webpage.

Thanks in advance for any help supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myProgress` is scoped within your `onload` handler, thus it can't be seen by other functions out of that scope.

```
var myProgress;
window.onload = function() {
    myProgress = new RGraph.VProgress('myProgress', 60, 100)
    // ...
};
```

Comment: You'll also need to redraw the canvas after you change the value: RGraph.Redraw();

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did that, and to change the value I did this:
function ChangeLevel(value){

 Tank.value=value;
    Tank.Draw();
 
 
 

}